# Push notifications... when the user disables them

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

I'm implementing push notifications in an iOS app. I was observing that, after I disable everything that is related to the notifications for my app in the device settings, the app still answers to

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
```

with the device token.

I also noticed that if you answer negatively to the first-start question, the device token is still available and returned by `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

Does it mean that push notifications are actually sent also to the devices that disabled notifications for a certain app, but sounds and badges are simply "hidden" (ignored)?

Comment: `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` returns nothing. What do you mean when you say it returns the device token?

Comment: sorry, I meant that the content of deviceToken is always valorized.